# I have an warning in the c# console, should I be worried?

Tags: c#, warnings, compiler-warnings

I have an error in one of my programs made with openwebkitsharp. When I compile it the program gives a warning in the console:

```
Warning There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the      
project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference     
"OpenWebKitSharp", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please   
consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project  
through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures     
'between your project and references, or take a dependency on references   '  
with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor   
architecture of your project.
```

What does it mean? How can I fix it? Or Should I just ignore it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing the platform target in the project properties to x86 instead of x64.

Comment: Where is the project  properties?

Comment: Instead of AnyCPU.  It won't work on any cpu, it requires a 32-bit process.  You only get one if you force the CLR to use the x86 jitter.  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Build tab.  Look around some more, this is supposed to be discoverable.  Press F1 when you don't understand something you see.